# IIS App settings Physical Path pointing to different folder location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, iis-6

In my local machine hosted a application on IIS and my port is :2001, and given physical path as below.
[image]

When I try to browse http://localhost:2001/services
it is pointing to different location with error.

```
Server cannot access application directory **'\\example.corp.local\dfsshares\home\Documents\My Web
        Sites\PostClosing.External.Api-Site3\**'. The directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security
        settings.</title>
```

Please suggest why it looking the code in \example.corp.local folder instead of C:/VSTS/

Comment: >Since this is too long and couldn't set it into comment. 

As far as I know, if we have set the IIS web site's physical path to  `C:/VSTS/.../..api/` , we could only access the `...api` folder's content. That means if we access the `http://localhost:2001/services`, we will try to find the `C:/VSTS/.../..api/services` folder, if there is no specific route setting in your application. The reason why you redirect to different folder may be related with the 404 error page setting in the IIS or there is any url rewrite settings.

Comment: Could be something in your hosts file - run a tracert on  http://localhost:2001 where is it going to? but I think it's probably what @BrandoZhang said with the folder location not being right. Check that it is going to the root - so should have the web.config in there then bin folders, views etc